# Formulario, Creado desde una Consulta PHP, No envía por AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, formularios

tengo la siguiente cuestión, y no consigo hacerla funcionar:

Al abrir una ventana "modal", hago una consulta a la base de datos, que me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
function verCliente() {

    $idcliente = $_POST['id'];

    $mysqli = getConn();

    $query = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE id_cliente = $idcliente";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);

    $ec = '<form id="form_edit_cliente" method="POST">
            <table id="table" width="100%" class="table table-hover table-mc-light-blue">';

    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $ec .= '<h2>Editar cliente #'.$row[id_cliente].'</h2>
                <h3>Datos Personales</h3>

                <input id="idc" type="hidden" value="'.$row[id_cliente].'">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="campoP">Nombre</td>
                        <td class="td"><input id="nombre" type="text" value="'.$row[nombre].'"></td>
                        <td class="td barcode" style="text-align:center" colspan="6" rowspan="2"></td>
                        <td class="campoP">Fecha Registro:</td>
                        <td class="td">' .$row[fecha_registro]. '</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="campoP">Apellidos</td>
                        <td class="td"><input id="apellidos" type="text" value="'.$row[apellidos].'"></td>
                        <td class="td" colspan="5"></td>
                        <td class="td"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="campoP">Telefono</td>
                        <td class="td"><input id="telefono" type="text" value="'.$row[telefono].'"></td>
                        <td class="td" colspan="5"></td>
                        <td class="td"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="campoP">Email</td>
                        <td class="td"><input id="email" type="text" value="'.$row[email].'"></td>
                        <td class="td" colspan="5"></td>
                        <td class="td"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <h3>Datos Comerciales</h3>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="campoP" style="width: 10%">Nombre Comercial</td>
                        <td class="td" style="width: 25%"><input id="ncomercial" type="text" value="'.$row[ncomercial].'"></td>
                        <td class="td" colspan="5"></td>
                        <td class="campoP" style="width: 10%">Nombre Fiscal</td>
                        <td class="td" style="width: 25%"><input id="nfiscal" type="text" value="'.$row[nfiscal].'"></td>
                        <td class="campoP">NIF/CIF</td>
                        <td class="td"><input id="cif" type="text" value="'.$row[cif].'"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="campoP">Direccion</td>
                        <td class="td"><input id="direccion" type="text" value="'.$row[direccion].'"></td>
                        <td class="td" colspan="5"></td>
                        <td class="campoP">Ciudad</td>
                        <td class="td"><input id="ciudad" type="text" value="'.$row[ciudad].'"></td>
                        <td class="campoP">CP</td>
                        <td class="td"><input id="cp" type="text" value="'.$row[cp].'"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>';
    }

    $ec .= '</table>
            <br><br>
            <center><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Editar Cliente"></center>
            </form>';

    return $ec;
}
```

Hasta aquí, todo es correcto,  el `form` se genera bien, y saca los datos bien.

A continuación, tengo un evento, para enviar este `form`, a través de `ajax`.

```
$("#form_edit_cliente").submit(function(e){

      var idc = $('#idc').val()
      var nombre = $('#nombre').val()
      var apellidos = $('#apellidos').val()
      var telefono = $('#telefono').val()
      var email = $('#email').val()
      var ncomercial = $('#ncomercial').val()
      var nfiscal = $('#nfiscal').val()
      var cif = $('#cif').val()
      var iva = $('#iva').val()
      var direccion = $('#direccion').val()
      var ciudad = $('#ciudad').val()
      var cp = $('#cp').val()

      e.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'php/update_cliente.php',
        data: {'idc': idc,
               'nombre': nombre,
               'apellidos': apellidos,
               'telefono': telefono,
               'email': email,
               'ncomercial': ncomercial,
               'nfiscal': nfiscal,
               'cif': cif,
               'iva': iva,
               'direccion': direccion,
               'ciudad': ciudad,
               'cp': cp
              }
      })
      .done(function(params){

        alert('El cliente ha sido editado correctamente');
        $('#editarCliente').hide();
        location.reload();

      })
      .fail(function(){
        alert("Error 01x234");
      })
});
```

**¿Que sucede a partir de aqui?**

Pues, intento acceder a este `php`:

```
function updateCliente() {

    $idc = $_POST['idc'];

    $mysqli = getConn();

    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $apellidos = $_POST['apellidos'];
    $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $ncomercial = $_POST['ncomercial'];
    $nfiscal = $_POST['nfiscal'];
    $cif = $_POST['cif'];
    $iva = $_POST['iva'];
    $direccion = $_POST['direccion'];
    $ciudad = $_POST['ciudad'];
    $cp = $_POST['cp'];

    $query = 'UPDATE clientes SET nombre = '.$nombre.', apellidos = '.$apellidos.', telefono = '.$telefono.', email = '.$email.', ncomercial = '.$ncomercial.', nfiscal = '.$nfiscal.', cif = '.$cif.', iva = '.$iva.', direccion = '.$direccion.', ciudad = '.$ciudad.', cp = '.$cp.' WHERE id_cliente = '.$idc.'';

    if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $query)) {
        echo "ok";
    } else {
        echo "fail" . mysqli_error($mysqli);
    }

}
```

- Al darle al `submit`, me está recargando la página, con lo que estoy deduciendo, que no me entra al código de jQuery.
- He probado antes del preventDefault, hacer un console.log de las variables, y no me dice absolutamente nada por consola, ya que recarga la página.
- También a través de `response`, en el `done` de ajax, he intentado ver que sucede con la consulta, pero al recargarme la página no puedo evaluar nada.

Espero alguien pueda porfavor ayudarme a solventar este fallo.
Gracias.

Comment: Antes de esto: $("#form_edit_cliente").submit(function(e){ intenta poner un console.log($("#form_edit_cliente").length) y dime que te devuelve

Comment: Me devuelve un 0, :/

Comment: Vale, al abrir el "modal", carga la consulta, y me retorna 1, me cargaba un 0, debido a que no existe el form, si no abro el modal.

Comment: entonces en el evento onshow del modal es que tienes que poner el escucha del evento submit de tu formulario.

Comment: Al darle a submit, el formulario se destruye, por eso no puede pasar datos, porque al darle submit, el form ya no existe, voy a tener que intentar cargarlo por html, y rellenar los valores.